# Visual Studio - View multiple variables in Memory View

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I want to see the content of multiple variables at once in the Memory View window of Visual Studio 2013. I have put a breakpoint on my program and then went to debug -> windows -> Memory -> Memory 1.
I now that if I write in the address box &variableName, it shows me the variable's address and its content, but what I want to do is to show the content of multiple variables at once.
Is this possible? How would you accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Open Memory 2 and view them side-by-side?

Comment: Or in your watch window `(int*)&var1, n` n is "size of array". Alternatively you can use any POD instead of int.